# C# - Ways to rename a directory

Tags: c#, directory, rename, ioexception

I'm using `Directory.Move(oldDir, newDir)` to rename a directory. Every now and then I get an `IOException` saying "Access to the path 'oldDir' is denied". However if I right click the directory in the explorer I can rename it without any issues.

**So my question is:** Are there any other ways to rename a directory without using `Directory.Move`?

I thought of using the command shell (`Process.Start()`) but this should be my last way of doing it.

---

*Further details*

The program is still running, I get the exception and can rename it manually in windows explorer (right click -> rename) while my cursor is paused on the breakpoint in the catch block. I also tried setting a breakpoint at `Directory.Move`, successfully renamed the directory in explorer (and back again), stepped over `Directory.Move` and ended up in the `catch (IOException)` again.

Here is my code

```
public bool Copy()
{
    string destPathRelease = ThisUser.DestPath + "\\Release";

    if (Directory.Exists(destPathRelease))
    {
        try
        {
            string newPath = ThisUser.DestPath + '\\' + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currBuildLabel) ? ("Release" + '_' + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")) : currBranchName) + '.' + currBuildLabel;
            Directory.Move(destPathRelease, newPath);
        }   
        catch (IOException)
        {
           // Breakpoint
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I just entered the method. I never touched the directory in my program before.

Since this way is not working for me I need to find another way to do so.

---

**Solution**

```
public bool Copy()
{
    string destPathRelease = ThisUser.DestPath + "\\Release";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT struc = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT();

    struc.hNameMappings = IntPtr.Zero;
    struc.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    struc.lpszProgressTitle = "Rename Release directory";
    struc.pFrom = destPathRelease + '\0';
    struc.pTo = ThisUser.DestPath + '\\' + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.currBuildLabel) ? ("Release" + '_' + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")) : this.currBranchName) + '.' + this.currBuildLabel + '\0';
    struc.wFunc = FileFuncFlags.FO_RENAME;

    int ret = SHFileOperation(ref struc);
}
```

Please note it's important to use `pTo` and `pFrom` as zero delimited double zero terminated strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2024022/961113

Comment: This will probably be to do with a file in the folder being `Read-only` and will have certain rights restricted

Comment: @Habib not sure what you are trying to say since there are no other methods as `Directory.Move` in this thread. @LukeHennerley if they would be read-only why can I rename them in the windows explorer? @both Have you read the full question? (not trying to be mean in any way)

Comment: @theknut Are you running this code from Visual studio with admin rights? if not run as admin and check, and also try to give full permission to all users to your source folder and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using P/Invoke to call the [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API (or the [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface). This is what Explorer uses in theory, so it should replicate the functionality more directly.

Comment: My hero! How do you actually know all this? Just being curious...

Answer (score 0):

Try using DirectoryInfo.MoveTo() instead of Directory.Move().

Also, check [this old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313799/renaming-a-directory-locks-renamed-dir-the-second-time-i-want-to-rename): it doesn't seems to have the same exception you're figuring out, but you can find some good advice.